# Visual Studio 2012 Dff tool only show one file

Tags: visual-studio-2012, diff

I was using the built in file compare utility in VS 2012 to compare two files in source code history.  It did something to cause one side of the comparison to go away and I have gone insane trying to figure out how to bring it back.  How do I make it so both files show side-by-side?

I have already tried: Closing all windows and re-opening them, restarting VS, Deleting the .SUO file and reloading the project. - No dice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The toolbar at the top of the window will have a dropdown list button that looks like two papers side by side.  Click on the button and select "Side-by-Side-Mode".

Comment: Thanks!  I will try this as soon as they let me out of my padded cell.

Comment: Thanks A bunch.Helped me.+ 1 for that

Comment: Only has two papers side-by-side if you're already on the side-by-side view!

Answer (score 0):

Choose the "Side by Side mode" in the tool bar.

[image]