# Visual studio 2019 - Git - Compare with unmodified

Tags: visual-studio-2019, diff

Suddenly, the diff window only shows the new version of the file.

When it used to show it (in green) and the HEAD version (in red), Side by side

How can i get it back ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtQLs.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referring to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27786551/visual-studio-2012-dff-tool-only-show-one-file/27786604).
You can try to use click "Side-by-side mode" on Visual Studio's toolbar

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzySf.png

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The suggestion given in link worked for me.